# Longest duration that can be specified with xsd:dayTimeDuration()

Tags: xslt, xpath, xsd, saxon

I have a simple question: what is the longest / "infinite" duration that can be specified using xsd:dayTimeDuration() (in the ISO8601 format)?

Thanks,
M.

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks, it was! It just happened that I was not in front of the PC when you answered :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The [W3C XSD specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration) doesn't restrict/specify the maximum value for an xs:dayTimeDuration**:

> The values of the Year, Month, Day, Hour and Minutes components are
>   not restricted but allow an arbitrary unsigned integer, i.e., an
>   integer that conforms to the pattern [0-9]+.

However, a particular implementation may impose its implementation-dependent limits.

**For example, Saxon allows this value**:

```
xs:dayTimeDuration('P999999999DT2H30M10S')
```

**but raises an error on this value** (one more 9-digit added to the days component):

```
xs:dayTimeDuration('P9999999999DT2H30M10S')
```

> FORG0001: Invalid duration value 'P9999999999DT2H30M10S' (non-numeric
>   component)

**XQSharp allows a bigger value  -- this is accepted**:

```
xs:dayTimeDuration('P999999999999999999DT2H30M10S')
```

**But one digit more in the days component raises an error**:

```
xs:dayTimeDuration('P9999999999999999999DT2H30M10S')

FODT0002: Underflow or overflow in construction of 'dayTimeDuration' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' from value 'P9999999999999999999DT2H30M10S'.
```

**Both of these two XPath implementations allow much bigger value-space than would be practically needed** -- just take into account that the age of the Universe is estimated at not more than 14 billion years, which is `5124000000000` days.

XQSharp allows for durations considerably bigger than the age of the Universe, while the maximum Saxon allows is just slightly less than the age of the Universe.